# Manifest not generated when building a c# project on OS X using mono

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono

I am trying to get a c# project to build on my mac. I use [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) and build it from the [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) editor. I get the error

> Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4431, 5): [MSB3030] Could not copy the file "obj/Debug/HemAdapter.Worker.exe.manifest" because it was not found.

My HemAdapter.Worker.csproj includes (changed the thumbprint for this post)

```
<PropertyGroup> 
<ManifestCertificateThumbprint>ABCDEFGHIJK1234556789</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <ManifestKeyFile>HemAdapter.Worker_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup> 
  <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The project builds fine on a PC.